# Building ncnn with Xcode Command Line Tools

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

This is my first time using Xcode Command Line Tools (13.2.1).  I am following the instructions on how to build ncnn here: https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/how-to-build#build-for-macos

Do I need to go into Xcode or can I just run the commands in the Terminal?

What is the function of Xcode Command Line Tools and how should it be applied in this case?

For further context I am converting a YOLOX.onnx model using these instructions: https://yolox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo/ncnn_cpp_readme.html

and I am getting the error when building ncnn: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make[2]: *** [tools/onnx/onnx2ncnn] Error 1 make[1]: *** [tools/onnx/CMakeFiles/onnx2ncnn.dir/all] Error 2`

The directions to convert onnx to ncnn tell me to:

````
cd <path of ncnn>
cd build/tools/ncnn```

However I do not have a ncnn folder inside of my tools folder...
````

Comment: Why do you want to use Xcode Command Line Tools?

Comment: What problems did you find with `brew install ncnn`?

Comment: Click on the link.  It was specified in the instructions and I'm unsure why.

Comment: I didn't hav cmake installed which is my bad.  but after I fixed that I got the error ```clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [tools/onnx/onnx2ncnn] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/onnx/CMakeFiles/onnx2ncnn.dir/all] Error 2```